# Check if android device has 'Draw over other app's' feature

Tags: android, permissions, overlay

I require the 'Draw over other apps' functionality to launch my activity from the background at a specific period. This works well on some devices, however I am testing it on a **Samsung A01** device with Android 10 and the feature isn't available.

Is there a way I can check if the feature is available?

Comment: The feature has been on all Android for years.  The user may not have given you permission, but the feature exists.  Did you mean how to check if you have permission?

Comment: @GabeSechan actually it doesn't exist on all devices. on Android Go devices, which are lower RAM devices, the feature isn't available. I was able to check for this flag thus resolving my issue

Comment: hi . did u get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I came to learn that the feature doesn't exists on [Android Go](https://www.android.com/versions/go-edition/) devices.

Using the method `isLowRamDevice()` from ActivityManager, I was able to tell whether or not the device supports the feature.

**How it works**

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean drawOverOtherAppsFeatureAvailable = activityManager.isLowRamDevice();
```

Comment: Is there any official documentation that would confirm your finding?

Comment: @MarcinBak https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#sysalert-go